# Why I am getting There is already an object named 'XXX' in the database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am doing ver simple stuff that makes sense,

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE xtype = 'TF' AND name = 'GetGeographyFromSourceID')
BEGIN
    DROP FUNCTION dbo.GetGeographyFromSourceID
END
GO

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetGeographyFromSourceID
(
    @SourceID INT
)
RETURNS  GEOGRAPHY
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Longitude FLOAT = 0; 
    DECLARE @Latitude FLOAT = 0; 
    DECLARE @Geo GEOGRAPHY;

    SELECT  @Longitude = Longitude, 
            @Latitude = Latitude 
    FROM    Sources 
    WHERE   ID = @SourceID; 

    SELECT @Geo = geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(' + CONVERT(VARCHAR( 100), @Longitude) + ' ' + CONVERT( VARCHAR( 100),@Latitude) + ')', 4326);

    RETURN(@Geo)
END
```

If exist than drop it and recreate it. But I am getting error `There is already an object named 'XXX' in the database?`

Comment: It's not making the drop....that if exist....try to use another condition....like count ;)

Comment: Just checked and found that it exist with type FN. Now what should I use TF or FN

Comment: Is there something else of that name? Try doing select * from sysobjects where name = 'GetGeographyFromSourceID' and see if it's some other object type. - Ah, you just did that!

Comment: You shouldn't be querying `sysobjects` these days. And you ought to use `OBJECTPROPERTY` to discover facts about objects rather than relying on obscure letter combinations.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever why?

Comment: Why you shouldn't use `sysobjects`? Because it will be removed from SQL Server one day, and if ever you're looking for a post-2000 feature, you won't find a way to get it through the old compatibility views. Why you should use `OBJECTPROPERTY`? That's a more nuanced/opinionated view, but seeing a query saying `IsScalarFunction` is a lot more readable (in my opinion) than `= 'FN'`. Last time I checked, we don't pay by the letter for using SQL Server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change it to FN instead of TF

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE xtype = 'FN' AND name = 'GetGeographyFromSourceID')
BEGIN
    DROP FUNCTION dbo.GetGeographyFromSourceID
END
GO

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetGeographyFromSourceID
(
    @SourceID INT
)
RETURNS  GEOGRAPHY
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Longitude FLOAT = 0; 
    DECLARE @Latitude FLOAT = 0; 
    DECLARE @Geo GEOGRAPHY;

    SELECT  @Longitude = Longitude, 
            @Latitude = Latitude 
    FROM    Sources 
    WHERE   ID = @SourceID; 

    SELECT @Geo = geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(' + CONVERT(VARCHAR( 100), @Longitude) + ' ' + CONVERT( VARCHAR( 100),@Latitude) + ')', 4326);

    RETURN(@Geo)
END
```

Comment: Yup this was the issue Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You are testing if a table valued function exists in the database, but the function you describe does not return a table. Replace your first part of the code ( before the go ) by this one and try again :

```
IF EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE id = object_id(N'GetGeographyFromSourceID') 
    AND xtype IN (N'FN', N'IF', N'TF')
)
    DROP FUNCTION GetGeographyFromSourceID
GO
```

Answer (score 4):

It looks like it's not actually hitting your DROP FUNCTION statement, because you are checking for `xtype = 'TF'` which only looks for Table Functions which this one isn't try `xtype='FN'` (Scalar Function)

[MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177596.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I know this has already been answered but just to add a point.  Given the way SQL handles object names it's generally best not to check when using this type of code.  When you create an object it's unique by name, not a combination of name + type.  Also a simpler way to check is to use the OBJECT_ID function.  Here are a few examples I did on the master database.

```
IF (OBJECT_ID('sysobjects') IS NOT NULL)
    PRINT OBJECT_ID('sysobjects')

IF (OBJECT_ID('sys.sysobjects') IS NOT NULL)
    PRINT OBJECT_ID('sys.sysobjects')

IF (OBJECT_ID('xyz') IS NOT NULL)
    PRINT OBJECT_ID('xyz')
```

The first two will evaluate to true and run the print (giving the same object id) and the third one will evaluate to false not running the print.